# Python function return none but it shouldn't

Tags: python, nonetype

I have a Python function (in a Kalman filter found somewhere) that I debugged with tons of print and it seems to works well.

The print before the return statement shows that the value is OK:

```
def step(self, z):
    #----code----
    #----alghoritm---
    print("self.x that I'm returning:", self.x) # The printed value is [-163.53868766 -160.27005497] so it is OK
    return self.x
    print("UNREACHED CODE") # OK, it is not printed
```

The function that called this is:

```
print("I call step with", tvec[0][0], tvec[1][0]) # Values are OK
estimate = self.kalfilt_trasl_x_y.step((tvec[0][0], tvec[1][0])) # The returned value is none
print("returned value: ", estimate) # Is none
```

Comment: If that print before the return shows that `self.x` has a value other than None, that function can't be returning None. Please show a [mcve] since something else is going on.

Comment: You say that you are calling `step` with `tvec[0][0], tvec[1][0]`. However, `step` takes only one argument in addition to the implicit `self`. So, you should call `some_object.step(some_argument)`

Answer (score 0):

finally found the problem.
You're right the problem was in another part of the code.
This problem was born since i reused a code intended for other without touching.
it was useful ipdb for debugging line by line.